# How to: Allow for a ListBox to have no selection

Tags: asp.net

I am wanting to allow for a user to deselect all values in a ListBox. Normally, when the user deselects all but one item, that one item cannot be deselected. I want to make it so it can be.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: I do not. I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: Can't you just hold down the Ctrl key and click on the last item? That should de-select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially I'm aware of two ways of doing this:

1. Add an empty item to the list. You can even name this item "None" or something similar. Using a text has the additional advantage that it informs the user.
2. Use JavaScript to unselect the item that is clicked if it is the last item.

Note, either way, you change the default behavior of the listbox, which is what users are accustomed to. Changing the default behavior is generally not a good idea, which is why I would go for option (1) being the clearest towards your users.